# Modify organization identifier in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on a `Xcode` project which was created years ago, now for some reason, I need to change the organisation identifier (the prefix before class name).
*Is it possible ? if yes, how?*

Answer (score 3):

if you want to continue with the same App uploaded over App store , you can not change bundle ID once it has been uploaded to App Store. It has been associated with different other location.

You can refer this [LINK](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW8) for more detail information

If you really want to change the bundle identifier, you need to create new App ID and then setup it as new App on App store.

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about 2 different things. The organisation identifier is a string entered when starting a new project and has a reverse-DNS format: com.mycompany... If you want to change it, open the Info.plist file of your app (or the dedicated editor of that file in Xcode), and change it. But as noted above, this makes impossible to update the app in the AppStore, if that was also your wish. Because the organisation identifier is used to build the "bundle identifier" which remains unique and unchanged during the app lifetime.

Now, the "prefix before class name" designates code files. It is the prefix you use to write your code, and most of it, the class names. Hence, to change it, use the usual "Refactor" feature. Open an interface file, select the class name, right-click on it, and find the entry "Rename..." in the menu. Follow the instruction.

For non-class elements, you might want to use the Search and Replace.